How to find the x-coordinate of the point circled(non-differentiable points) in this trigonometric function graph?
Clear["`*"]
w = 2;
f[x_] = Abs[Sin[w x]] + Cos[w x]
Plot[f[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]


How do I find the x-coordinate of the point circled in this trigonometric function graph?

SolveValues[f[x] == 1 && -2 \[Pi] <= x <= 2 \[Pi], x] // Sort
SolveValues[f[x] == -1 && -2 \[Pi] <= x <= 2 \[Pi], x] // Sort



The observation from the plotted points shows that the y-coordinates are either 1 or -1. Through solving equations, we can find the x-coordinates of these points. Now, what I need is a method to automatically label the x-coordinates of such points.


FunctionSingularities.

w = 2;
f[x_] = Abs[Sin[w x]] + Cos[w x];
expr = FunctionSingularities[f[x], x]
{Plot[f[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, Exclusions -> expr, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[5], Red}],
 Plot[f[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[x, First[expr] // Evaluate], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive@{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red}]}


Sin[2 x] == 0.



Reply to the comment.

Clear["Global`*"]; 
w = 2; 
f[x_] = Abs[Sin[(w + 1) x]] + Cos[w x] + Abs[Cos[w x]];
expr =  FunctionSingularities[f[x], x]

sol = Solve[{expr, -2 π <= x <= 2 π}, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point@{x, f[x]} /. sol}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]


Cos[2 x] == 0 || Sin[3 x] == 0.



Clear["Global`*"]; w = 2; f[x_] = Abs[Sin[(w + 1) x]] + Cos[w x] + Abs[Cos[w x]]; expr = FunctionSingularities[f[x], x] Plot[f[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, Exclusions -> expr,   ExclusionsStyle -> Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[5], Red}]

If the function above has multiple absolute values, why aren't the points identified?

Use Exclusions -> List @@ expr instead if there are more than one alternatives in expr.

How can I change the red square points in the first set of code to red circular points?

These are discontinuities caused by Abs[Sin[w x]].
w = 2;
f[x_] := Abs[Sin[w x]] + Cos[w x]

Reduce[Abs[Sin[w x]] == 0, x]
Reduce[Abs[Sin[w x]] == 0 && -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi, x]
SolveValues[Abs[Sin[w x]] == 0 && -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi, x]

Plot[Abs[Sin[w x]] + Cos[w x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> Large, Point[{#, f[#]}] & /@ %}]




Why the discontinuities occur at the points where Abs[Sin[w x]] equals zero

@csn899 Absolute value function has discontinuities at crossings of x-axis.
